# $installer->addAttribute Some Settings Ignored

Tags: attributes, product-attribute, multiselect-attribute

Inside a mysql4 upgrade script for my module, I have the following:

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

// Code that builds the var $optionList is here

$collection = array(
    'label'             => 'Collection:',
    'input'             => 'multiselect',
    'default'           => '0',
    'class'             => '',
    'backend'           => '',
    'frontend'          => '',
    'source'            => '',
    'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
    'visible'           => true,
    'required'          => false,
    'user_defined'      => true,
    'searchable'        => true,
    'filterable'        => true,
    'comparable'        => true,
    'visible_on_front'  => true,
    'visible_in_advanced_search' => true,
    'unique'            => false,
    'option'            => $optionList
);

$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'collection', $collection);

$installer->endSetup();
```

All of the `=> true` settings that I have here are showing up as `No` on the final attribute edit screen in the Admin. (Screenshot: http://goo.gl/aSQ3wk)

Here is the `<resources>` section of my config.xml file:

```
<resources>
    <company_modulename_setup>
        <setup>
            <module>Company_Modulename</module>
            <class>Company_Modulename_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup</class>
        </setup>

        <connection>
            <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
    </company_modulename_setup>

    <company_modulename_write>
        <connection>
            <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
    </company_modulename_write>

    <company_modulename_read>
        <connection>
            <use>core_read</use>
        </connection>
    </company_modulename_read>
</resources>
```

I'm not sure why all of these settings aren't taking. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you are using the wrong setup class. The right one for product or category attributes is `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup` (since Magento CE 1.6 or EE 1.11). You have to define it in your config.xml as follows:

```
<resources>
    <yourmodule_setup>
        <setup>
            <module>Namespace_YourModule</module>
            <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
        </setup>
    </yourmodule_setup>
</resources>
```

Comment: Andreas: See edited post for my <resources> section. My class Company_Modulename_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup. Should it extend Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup?

Comment: I changed which class mine extends to Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup and it works now. Thanks!